# Bash script eval with aws command producing "command not found"

Tags: bash, eval

I have a short bash script to take in an int from a user to identify to select a certain eks cluster.

When I use `eval $(aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name eventplatform$input)`

I get the error: `Updated: command not found`

This is resolved if I simply change the command to just `aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name eventplatform$input`

Why is the eval command not working for this?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e

read -p "Which cluster are you trying to access? (int >= 0): " input

while [[ -n ${input//[0-9]/} ]]
do
    read -p "Which cluster are you trying to access? (int >= 0): " input
done

eval $(aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name eventplatform$input)
```

Comment: `set -x` is your friend to enable trace logging so you can see what's going on. That said, you almost certainly shouldn't be using `eval` here. What's the point of it?

Comment: (btw, `set -e` is generally a bad idea; it makes your script _far_ harder for readers/reviewers to understand its behavior, not to mention authors. See [the exercises section of BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises))

Comment: The command you are using modifies your `~/.kube/config` file. It does not output text that can be executed by a shell.

Comment: ...also, if you _are_ going to use `eval`, there is basically no circumstance where `eval $(something)` is more correct than `eval "$(something)"` -- the former breaks the output of `something` into words and expands each word as a glob expression before combining them back into a single string and trying to parse that string as code. But collect the xtrace log so we know what's happening during execution before trying to go down that road.

Comment: (also, it's arguably a bug that AWS is emitting their "Updated" message to stdout instead of stderr, which is where POSIX states that diagnostic data -- a category which includes status updates meant for human readers -- belongs).

Answer (score 2):

The `eval` command isn't *supposed* to work for this (whatever you expect "work" to mean in this context).

`eval` runs data as code. Only programs that write well-formed shell commands or scripts to their stdout as data should have that data `eval`ed.

Comment: Yes.  Eval is rarely useful. Eval is for advanced users, and most advanced users usually know better than to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. `eval` argument should be a string or something that exists to run, not output of other comments

```bash
#!/bin/bash

eval "ls" # okay 
# file1.txt
# file2.txt

eval $(ls); # error
# bash: file1.txt: command not found
```

See `help eval`

> eval: eval [arg ...]
> Execute arguments as a shell command.
>
> ```
> Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
> and execute the resulting commands.
> ```